# application not start after deploying grails 4 app on tomcat 9 & Java 8

Tags: java, grails, tomcat9

1. While deploying, deployment completed successfully, but the application is not starting up. Below are the logs -

> 01-May-2022 15:40:53.004 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/9.0.62
> 01-May-2022 15:40:53.012 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Mar 31 2022 14:34:15 UTC
> 01-May-2022 15:40:53.013 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version number: 9.0.62.0
> 01-May-2022 15:40:53.014 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Windows 10
> 01-May-2022 15:40:53.014 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            10.0
> 01-May-2022 15:40:53.015 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
> 01-May-2022 15:40:53.015 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_211
> 01-May-2022 15:40:53.016 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_211-b12
> 01-May-2022 15:40:53.016 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
> 01-May-2022 15:40:53.017 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         F:\apache-tomcat-9.0.62-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-9.0.62
> 01-May-2022 15:40:53.017 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         F:\apache-tomcat-9.0.62-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-9.0.62
> 01-May-2022 15:40:53.019 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=F:\apache-tomcat-9.0.62-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-9.0.62\conf\logging.properties
> 01-May-2022 15:40:53.019 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
> 01-May-2022 15:40:53.020 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
> 01-May-2022 15:40:53.020 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
> 01-May-2022 15:40:53.021 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dignore.endorsed.dirs=
> 01-May-2022 15:40:53.022 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=F:\apache-tomcat-9.0.62-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-9.0.62
> 01-May-2022 15:40:53.030 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=F:\apache-tomcat-9.0.62-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-9.0.62
> 01-May-2022 15:40:53.031 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=F:\apache-tomcat-9.0.62-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-9.0.62\temp
> 01-May-2022 15:40:53.048 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent Loaded Apache Tomcat Native library [1.2.32] using APR version [1.7.0].
> 01-May-2022 15:40:53.049 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true], UDS [true].
> 01-May-2022 15:40:53.050 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR/OpenSSL configuration: useAprConnector [false], useOpenSSL [true]
> 01-May-2022 15:40:53.068 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.initializeSSL OpenSSL successfully initialized [OpenSSL 1.1.1n  15 Mar 2022]
> 01-May-2022 15:40:54.540 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
> 01-May-2022 15:40:54.651 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Server initialization in [2382] milliseconds
> 01-May-2022 15:40:54.759 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
> 01-May-2022 15:40:54.762 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.62]
> 01-May-2022 15:40:54.841 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [F:\apache-tomcat-9.0.62-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-9.0.62\webapps\ROOT.war]
> 01-May-2022 15:40:56.129 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase.createSecureRandom Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [469] milliseconds.
> 01-May-2022 15:40:56.205 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [F:\apache-tomcat-9.0.62-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-9.0.62\webapps\ROOT.war] has finished in [1,365] ms
> 01-May-2022 15:40:56.208 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [F:\apache-tomcat-9.0.62-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-9.0.62\webapps\docs]
> 01-May-2022 15:40:56.296 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [F:\apache-tomcat-9.0.62-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-9.0.62\webapps\docs] has finished in [89] ms
> 01-May-2022 15:40:56.298 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [F:\apache-tomcat-9.0.62-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-9.0.62\webapps\examples]
> 01-May-2022 15:40:57.502 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [F:\apache-tomcat-9.0.62-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-9.0.62\webapps\examples] has finished in [1,205] ms
> 01-May-2022 15:40:57.506 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [F:\apache-tomcat-9.0.62-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-9.0.62\webapps\host-manager]
> 01-May-2022 15:40:57.612 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [F:\apache-tomcat-9.0.62-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-9.0.62\webapps\host-manager] has finished in [106] ms
> 01-May-2022 15:40:57.617 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [F:\apache-tomcat-9.0.62-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-9.0.62\webapps\manager]
> 01-May-2022 15:40:57.715 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [F:\apache-tomcat-9.0.62-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-9.0.62\webapps\manager] has finished in [98] ms
> 01-May-2022 15:40:57.731 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
> 01-May-2022 15:40:57.816 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in [3164] milliseconds

2. Below is the build.config file

   ````
       repositories {
           maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
       }
       dependencies {
           classpath "org.grails:grails-gradle-plugin:4.0"
           classpath "org.grails.plugins:hibernate5:7.0.0"
           classpath "gradle.plugin.com.github.erdi.webdriver-binaries:webdriver-binaries-gradle-plugin:2.0"
           classpath "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-gradle:3.0.10"
       }
   }

   apply plugin:"eclipse"
   apply plugin:"idea"
   apply plugin:"war"
   apply plugin:"org.grails.grails-web"
   apply plugin:"com.github.erdi.webdriver-binaries"
   apply plugin:"org.grails.grails-gsp"
   apply plugin:"com.bertramlabs.asset-pipeline"

   repositories {
       maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
   }

   configurations {
       runtimeClasspath {
           extendsFrom developmentOnly
       }
   }

   war {
       enabled = true
   }

   dependencies {
       compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging"
       compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure"
       compile "org.grails:grails-core"
       compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
       compile "org.grails:grails-web-boot"
       compile "org.grails:grails-logging"
       compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-rest"
       compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-databinding"
       compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-i18n"
       compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-services"
       compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-url-mappings"
       compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-interceptors"
       compile "org.grails.plugins:cache", {
           exclude group: "org.codehaus.groovy", module: "groovy-all"
       }
       compile "org.grails.plugins:async"
       compile "org.grails.plugins:scaffolding"
       compile "org.grails.plugins:events"
       compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate5"
       compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.4.0.Final"
       compile "org.grails.plugins:gsp"
       compileOnly "io.micronaut:micronaut-inject-groovy"
       console "org.grails:grails-console"
       profile "org.grails.profiles:web"
       runtime "org.glassfish.web:el-impl:2.1.2-b03"
       runtime "com.h2database:h2"
       runtime "javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.0"
       runtime "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-grails:3.0.10"


       testCompile "org.grails:grails-gorm-testing-support"
       testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core"
       testCompile "org.grails:grails-web-testing-support"
       testCompile "org.grails.plugins:geb"
       testCompile "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-remote-driver:3.14.0"
       testCompile "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-api:3.14.0"
       testCompile "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-support:3.14.0"
       testRuntime "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-chrome-driver:3.14.0"
       testRuntime "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-firefox-driver:3.14.0"
       testRuntime group: 'io.micronaut', name: 'http-client', version: '1.0.0.RC2'
       compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:4.0.0.RC2'
       compile "org.grails.plugins:spring-security-rest:3.0.0.RC1"
       runtime 'org.grails.plugins:ajax-tags:1.0.0.RC1'

   }```
   ````